# Gmail: bulk delete several consecutive inbox email without doing it programmatically and without selecting everything on the screen

Tags: gmail

I want to delete all mail from my inbox from e-mail A to e-mail B on the user inteface. I want to check one box, then check the other box, and when I check the second box all checkboxes in between become checked. And no I don't want to do this programmatically. I've tried Alt-Click and Ctrl-Click, but these done't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Gmail, when you <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> an entry, the entry as well as everything up to the previously clicked or shift-clicked entry (if any) also becomes checked.